# Error inflating class PlotView

Tags: android, mono, oxyplot

i am trying to use oxyplot on android, and i am getting the error "error inflating class PlotView"

i have built and referenced OxyPlot.XamarinAndroid, and the only thing i try to do is add it in the xml like this:

```
<PlotView
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="150dp"
p1:id="@+id/SmallPlot"
/>
```

this plot goes into a TabHost, and exception is thrown when i do the "tabs.Setup();"

Can you please help me? Could the Tabs be related? Am i missing something?
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the whole layout? What is the plotview package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution:

the tag to use in the AXML is `<oxyplot.xamarinandroid.PlotView/>` and not `<PlotView/>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be the bottom code I believe.

```
  <OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android.PlotView
          android:id="@+id/plotView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```